# Flow js predicate function

Tags: javascript, flowtype, predicate

I'm trying to use a predicate function (https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-predicate-functions), but it's not working.

Given the following code:

```
/* @flow */
// Some function we need exact types for
const someFunc = (addressLine1: string, city: string, zip: string) => ({})

// Predicate
function checker(addressLine1: ?string, city: ?string, zip: ?string): boolean %checks {
  return Boolean(addressLine1 && city && zip)
}

// Logic
const addressLine1: ?string = 'a'
const city: ?string = 'b'
const zip: ?string = 'c'

if(checker(addressLine1, city, zip)){
  someFunc(addressLine1, city, zip)
}
```

After reading the docs, I would expect the code above to not have any errors, but Flow complains that `addressLine1`, `city`, and `zip` might be undefined when calling `someFunc()`.

Here's a working (well, erroring) example: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoYwwGU4FsCmYUArgHYDGALgJZylgKGn74AmY+AHgIZViUBPAA74AzkTgAnVOTqjKYUXnwAxMuTABeMAApurVpLGiAMtWYBGAFyLKk8wHMANGHLVBN+fdLOwAL2ohTztHAEotAD5dAG8AX1DUdEwABSNWanJuSnxUEgoaOlcAC3xyAGt8ST0DI1FTc3xrMAB+L0cXNw8Wtp8XAKDukJ9QmwAjODgYfG56AFJyEvLxaNQwMCNKYkl6ACEJqZnqw2MzSzAAMnPXdwELq-6E2MSMMBM4BwyZOQV9Y7rTxo2VpDBxaMAAcm44K+pHk1y6wO8oO04NG0NksIU-SBPWREPI0NQ1CgOgWpQqVV+tXqlg6Nz6gVCoRWayUBDUFCO1IBFjpggZQkeQA

Any insight into what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue in this case was wrapping the return value in `Boolean()`. Once I removed that the errors were resolved.

Corrected Code:

```
/* @flow */
// Some function we need exact types for
const someFunc = (addressLine1: string, city: string, zip: string) => ({})

// Predicate
function checker(addressLine1: ?string, city: ?string, zip: ?string): boolean %checks {
  return !!addressLine1 && !!city && !!zip
}

// Logic
const addressLine1: ?string = 'a'
const city: ?string = 'b'
const zip: ?string = 'c'

if(checker(addressLine1, city, zip)){
  someFunc(addressLine1, city, zip)
}
```

In "Try Flow": https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoYwwGU4FsCmYUArgHYDGALgJZylgKGn74AmY+AHgIZViUBPAA74AzkTgAnVOTqjKYUXnwAxMuTABeMAApurVpLGiAMtWYBGAFyLKk8wHMANGHLVBN+fdLOwAL2ohTztHAEotAD5dAG8AX1DUdEwABSNWanJuSnxUEgoaOlcAC3xyAGt8ST0DI1FTc3xrMAB+L0cXNw8Wtp8XAKDukJ9QmwAjODgYfG56AFJyEvLxaNQwMCNKYkl6AEId-UNjM0swADJTsD3OgTOLvf7UWMSMMBM4BwyZOQUD2vrLGytIYOLRgADk3DBX1I8lc7gEgJ6IO0YNGUNkMIU-URwNBYPIUNQ1CgOgWpQqVV+RwaFg68L6gVCoRWayUBDUFGqhzqx0adMEDKECViQA